# how to dispose all jframes that running in java?

Tags: java

Hello i wanna know how to dispose all jframes that running in java because i have to get back to login frame every 15 mins i use a timer for that

```
  public static void autoLogout() {
        new Timer(900000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  main.mainpage.loging.setVisible(true);
                  main.mainpage.mainpnl.setVisible(false);

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have multiple JFrames instead of a single `JFrame` with `CardLayout` for example?

Comment: in my program there are several jframes example Login and dashbord are in one jframe. stock info is in anther one. i have to add a listner that if user is not working it should rederect to login fram

Comment: `stock info is in anther one.` - stock info should be in a child dialog. Same as the login. The application should be a single main JFrame and then you display modal JDialogs when you have additional processing. Think of the way a browser works. You have the main window with a menubar and toolbar. Then when you click on variable functions other dialogs appear as required.

Comment: yeahh im gonna have to do that.. thanx mate. cheers!